# How to apply a DataTemplate for a derived type in non-referenced assembly

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datatemplate

I'm using DataTemplates to display items in a list control. The view models in the list come from different assemblies, but they all derive from the same base class. The viewer is in the assembly with the base class and is bound to a list of the base class items. My DataTemplates for each item are based on type, so WPF should pick the DataTemplate for the Type of the view model in the list.

The problem I'm having is that the derived view model and its DataTemplate are in a different assembly. The assembly with the derived view model references the base assembly. so the base assembly cannot reference the derived assembly.

Example code:

ViewModelB derives from ViewModelA. The classes are in assemblies A and B respectively.

```
class ViewModelA   // in assembly A
{
}

class ViewModelB : ViewModelA    // in assembly B
{
}
```

CollectionViewModel contain a list of ViewModelA objects

```
class CollectionViewModel
{
    List<ViewModelA> m_Items;

    List<ViewModelA> Items 
    { 
         get { return m_Items}
    }
}
```

In XAML the list is bound to an ItemsControl for display

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

Each view model in the list will be displayed by there respective DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelA}">  // in assembly A
    <UserControlForViewModel_A/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelB}">  // in assembly B
    <UserControlForViewModel_B/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Which assembly is your ItemsControl in?

Comment: In situations like this I'd use a custom DataTemplateSelector. I've got a couple answers with details about the DTS, I think there's one that has an example of how to create one https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1228+is%3Aa+datatemplateselector

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what a "base assembly" is? Will has a good suggestion, by the way.

Comment: @EdPlunkett The items control and the list are both in assembly A. The items themselves and their respective DataTemplates come from assembly A or B.

Comment: @EdPlunkett The base assembly is the assembly with the base class (ViewModelA) from which the class ViewModelB derives.

Comment: A DataTemplateSelector will have the same problem if it is defined in assembly A because it would not know about ViewModelB or the DataTemplate for ViewModelB.
I could define the DataTemplate in assembly B because B knows about ViewModelA and ViewModelB. But then I would have to pass the DTS into assembly A for it to use.

Comment: So the application, the executable, is either Assembly B or something else (this is the kind of information that should have been in the original question). The application starts up and loads some XAML from Assembly A. I don't know how it gets it, because we're playing 20 Questions. And somehow, from somewhere, the ItemsControl in that XAML from Assembly A gets a collection whose type parameter is ClassA. Some or all of the objects in it are actually instances of derived classes defined in Assembly B. Their DataTemplates are defined in Assembly B as well.

Comment: I think it might be a good idea for somebody, somewhere, to get an instance of a `DataTemplateSelector` subclass from Assembly B and pass it to Assembly A. I don't know who or how, because I don't know anything about your architecture.